# Conditionally Formatting JSX on Button Click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, conditional-formatting

I have an app that first shows a list of cars based on props, but clicking a `sort` button converts the display into an alphabetized list.

I'm trying to set a function that changes the state of `buttonClicked` every time the `sort` button is clicked (which runs `sortAlphabetically`.

The conditional rendering tutorial in the React docs is focused on the text *within* a button, but I'm trying to conditionally render the JSX in my render method based on whether or not a separate button was clicked.

Here's my code so far, which returns `Parsing error: this is a reserved word`.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import CarCard from '../components/CarCard';
import CarForm from './CarForm';
import './Cars.css';
import { getCars } from '../actions/cars';
import { sortCar } from '../actions/cars';

Component.defaultProps = {
  cars: { cars: [] }
}

class Cars extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
      this.state = {
        cars: [],
        sortedCars: [],
        buttonClicked: false
      };
  }

sortAlphabetically = () => {
    handleSortClick();
    const newArray = [].concat(this.props.cars.cars)
    const orgArray = newArray.sort(function (a,b) {
      var nameA = a.name.toUpperCase();
      var nameB = b.name.toUpperCase();
      if (nameA < nameB) {
        return -1;
      } else if (nameA > nameB) {
        return 1;
      } 
      return 0;
    })  
    this.setState({ cars: {cars: orgArray} })
}

componentDidMount() {
     this.props.getCars()
    // this.setState({cars: this.props.cars})
  }

 handleSortClick() {
    this.setState({
      buttonClicked: !this.state.buttonClicked})
  }

render() {

  const buttonClicked = this.state.buttonClicked
  let display;

  if (this.state.buttonClicked = false) {
    display = {this.state.cars.cars && this.state.cars.cars.map(car => <CarCard key={car.id} car={car}/>)}  
  } else {
{this.props.cars.cars && this.props.cars.cars.map(car => <CarCard key={car.id} car={car} />)}  
  }
    return (
<div className="CarsContainer">
    <h3>Cars Container</h3> 
        <button onClick={this.sortAlphabetically}>Sort</button>
        {display}
        <CarForm />
    </div>
    );
  }
}

 const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return ({
    cars: state.cars
  })
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    sortCar: (cars) => dispatch(sortCar(cars)),
    getCars: (cars) => dispatch(getCars(cars))
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Cars);
```

Ultimately, I'm trying to do the following:

- have initial state of `buttonClicked` set to false
- toggle the boolean value of `buttonClicked` whenever `sortAplhabetically` is run
- display `this.state.cars.cars && this.state.cars.cars.map(car => <CarCard key={car.id} car={car}/>)}` when **false**
- display `{this.props.cars.cars && this.props.cars.cars.map(car => <CarCard key={car.id} car={car} />)}` when **true**

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm pretty sure your default props are defined wrong.  They should be after your `Cars` class and the syntax should be changed to `Cars.defaultProps = {...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stored my JSX in variables that would render on condition:

```
render() {

 let message
   if (this.state.buttonClicked) {
    message = this.state.cars.cars && this.state.cars.cars.map(car => <CarCard key={car.id} car={car}/>)  
  } else {
  message = this.props.cars.cars && this.props.cars.cars.map(car => <CarCard key={car.id} car={car} />)
 }

return (
<div className="CarsContainer">
    <h3>Cars Container</h3> 
    <button onClick={this.sortAlphabetically}>Sort</button>
    {message}
    <CarForm />
</div>
);
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simplest solution that i can come up with. You WILL need to substitute your own code in some places. But some of your code has been removed because it is causing problems and overly complicating the issue. You should be able to find a solution to your problem within this answer, it wont be as simple as a copy paste however.

your checklist:

- have initial state of buttonClicked set to false: done
- toggle the boolean value of buttonClicked whenever sortAplhabetically is run: instead of doing this i simply sort the array of cars.

For the other two checklist items (omitted due to code formatting issues). You probably want to use state, not if X state otherwise props.

```
class Cars extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      carList: [{ id: 'apple' }, { id: 'orange' }, { id: 'zealot' }]
    }
  }

  sortAlphabetical () {
    this.setState({
      carList: this.state.carList.reverse()
    })
  }

  render () {
    const CarsList = () => {
      return this.state.carList.map(car => {
        return <li>{car.id}</li>
      })
    }

    return (
      <div className='CarsContainer'>
        <h3>Cars Container</h3>
        <button onClick={this.sortAlphabetical.bind(this)}>Sort</button>
        <CarsList />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

NOTE: i've omitted some of your code because i do not have the ability to re-create your environment without access to all the files used. This should still be sufficient for getting across the basic ideas.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a ternary operator. Like this

`{this.state.buttonClicked ? ({this.props.cars.cars && this.props.cars.cars.map(car => <CarCard key={car.id} car={car} />)}) : (this.state.cars.cars && this.state.cars.cars.map(car => <CarCard key={car.id} car={car}/>)})}`

Comment: I'm getting an error due to `this` being a `reserved word`. I don't think I can use `this` this way

Comment: On `{this.state.buttonClicked ?`

Comment: Thats what I am trying to tell, write the code above inside your render function